# Prove that the difference of two chi square distributions is a chi square distribution, using the moment generating function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions, chi-squared

I am reading through ***modern mathematical statistics with applications by Devore and Berk***. I came across the following "exercise left to the reader" and I couldn't figure it out easily.

**Question**:

> Use moment generating functions to show that if  $$X_3 = X_1+X_2, $$
> with $$X_1 \sim \chi ^2_{\nu_1},$$  $$X_3 \sim \chi ^2_{\nu_3},$$  and
> $$\nu_3 > \nu_1$$ and $X_1, X_2$ are independent, then $X_2 \sim \chi^2_{\nu_3-\nu_1}$

**Attempt**:
Using the MGF we would have
$$ M_{X_2}(t) = M_{X_3-X_1}(t) = M_{X_3}(t)M_{X_1}(-t) = (1+2t)^{-\nu_3/2}(1-2t)^{-\nu_1/2} .$$

I do not see an easy way to deal with $(1+2t)^{-\nu_3/2}(1-2t)^{-\nu_1/2} $ since the exponents are not the same.

Comment: How does $M_{X_3-X_1}(t) = M_{X_3}(t)M_{X_1}(-t)$?

Comment: Your starting point should be $M_3(t)=M_1(t)M_2(t)$.  You seem to be assuming that $X_3$ and $X_1$ are independent in your displayed equation.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I got it now. It makes perfect sense. I see where I went wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$M_{X_3}(t) = M_{X_2}(t) M_{X_1}(t) \text{ from independence}$$
$$\text{ so we have that } \frac{M_{X_3}(t)}{M_{X_1}(t)} = M_{X_2}(t)$$
$$\text{and from the MGF of a chi square distribution (for $t< 1/2), $ we have that } \frac{(1+2t)^{-\frac{\nu_3}{2}}}{(1+2t)^{-\frac{\nu_1}{2}}} = (1+2t)^{-\frac{\nu_3-\nu_1}{2}}$$
$$\text{ which is precisely the MGF of } \chi^2_{\nu_3-\nu_1}$$

$$\text{So we have that } X_2 \sim \chi^2_{\nu_3-\nu_1}$$

Comment: Why not give a correct proof by finishing this attempt of yours instead of accepting misleading answers?

Comment: @StubbornAtom ok I just did. I thought the other answer seemed correct and felt guilty answering and accepting my own.

Comment: Use correct formula for MGF (mentioning when MGF exists). Plus there is a typo in your question which should say $\nu_3>\nu_1$, from which the conclusion follows.

Answer (score 0):

Prove it in the following way:

$X_1 \sim \chi_{v_3}^2$

suppose that

$X_2 \sim \chi_{v_3-v_1}^2$

thus for independence you know that

$$M_{X_1}(t)M_{X_2}(t)=(1-2t)^{-\frac{v_1}{2}}(1-2t)^{-\frac{v_3-v_1}{2}}=(1-2t)^{-\frac{v_3}{2}}$$

that is exactly the MGF of the distribution of $X_3$